# Views didn't return an HttpResponse object error

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views

I am importing the excel data to MySQL database. While doing that i am getting one error in view.

My views.py file:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
                     user="root", 
                     passwd="", 
                     db="upload")
test = 'c'

def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            newdoc = newdoc.docfile.name
            newdoc = str(newdoc)
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(newdoc)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            c = 1
            while c < len(sh.col(0)):
                first = sh.col_values(0)[c]
                second = sh.col_values(1)[c]
                x = db.cursor()
                db.set_character_set('utf8')
                x.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
                x.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
                x.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
                x.execute("INSERT INTO testcont_content(title, description) VALUES('%s','%s');"%(first,second))
                db.commit()
                c=c+1
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload.views.list'))
        else:
            form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
        documents = Document.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('upload/list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'test': test,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am getting the error at line "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload.views.list'))":

```
Internal Server Error: /upload/list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 133, in get_response
    raise ValueError("The view %s.%s didn't return an HttpResponse object." % (callback.__module__, view_name))
ValueError: The view upload.views.list didn't return an HttpResponse object.
[06/Jun/2014 10:39:20] "GET /upload/list/ HTTP/1.1" 500 60044
```

My forms.py file is:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
    )
```

urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^list/$', views.list, name='list'),
)
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Your reverse('upload.views.list') is going to fail because your url should say url(r'^list/$', views.list, name='upload.views.list')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a `HttpResponse` object (or a subclass, like `HttpResponseRedirect`) at every request. In your code, you are checking if the request is sent via POST, but you forgot to return a response otherwise. Your view should be something like:

```
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            # ... Your process
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # We reach there when the HttpResponseRedirect has not been called
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('upload/list.html', 
                              {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'test': test,}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first line:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

there is no else part. When you perform a redirect, the method is not post. Thus, an else part cannot be found and so there is no HttpResponse object returned